# Change line style of CPScatterPlot for different points

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm using coreplot on ios and have a scatterplot. Is it possible to vary the line style depending on the point being plotted? I've only found how to set it for the whole plot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Make sure your graph delegate conforms to `CPScatterPlotDelegate` by implementing -`symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:`. Here's a working implementation which returns a different symbol for the index which matches `_selectedIndex`:

```
- (CPPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{   
    CPMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
    CPPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    plotSymbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;

    if (_selectedIndex != NSNotFound && index == _selectedIndex) 
    {
        plotSymbol.symbolType = CPPlotSymbolTypeDiamond;
        plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(12, 12);
        plotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor redColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        plotSymbol.symbolType = CPPlotSymbolTypeEllipse 
        plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(8, 8);
        plotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor greenColor]];  
    }
    return plotSymbol;
}
```

Comment: Thats a good answer, however I think its not what he asked for. I guess the idea is that how can you make a normal line graph becoming a dotted line graph for example. Your suggestion shows how to change the plot symbols depending on the current index. I would be glad if you can explain how to change the style of the line midway-through the graph. Thanks

Comment: Just in case, if somebody wants to use the symbolForScatterPlot he has to use the CPTScatterPlotDataSource delegate.