# How to change the color of a plot symbol when selected iPhone

Tags: ios, select, plot, highlight, symbols

I found similar questions on this site and I tried some methods, but I didn't succeed.

I want the plot symbol to change its color when selected, in order to see exactly which symbol was selected. I looked in the CPTTestApp (in the Core Plot examples folder), to see the example and from what I see on this site, I have to work with an plot parameter, in order to decide whether to return a custom symbol or not. But I don't know what this plot parameter is.

How can I detect which symbol was selected, in order to change the color for it? By using the index?

Sorry for being a little bit confused on how to use this method. I made researches and I will continue, but maybe someone has an idea.

I found a method symbolForScatterPlot that should give me the expected result, but I don't know what variable selectedIndex is and how I should declare it and where else to use it. I took this method from here [Change line style of CPScatterPlot for different points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479350/change-line-style-of-cpscatterplot-for-different-points)
and it looks like this:

```
 - (CPPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{   
CPMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
CPPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
plotSymbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;

if (_selectedIndex != NSNotFound && index == _selectedIndex) 
{
    plotSymbol.symbolType = CPPlotSymbolTypeDiamond;
    plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(12, 12);
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor redColor]];
}
else
{
    plotSymbol.symbolType = CPPlotSymbolTypeEllipse 
    plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(8, 8);
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPFill fillWithColor:[CPColor greenColor]];  
}
return plotSymbol;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your question is in two parts : first locating the selected point, then changing the color of it.

For locating a selected point, you have to set a delegate for your CPTScatterPlot instance in order to detect the touch event.  (Here currentPlot is my  CPTScatterPlot instance)

```
currentPlot.delegate                        = self;
currentPlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 10.0f;
```

The second line enable a certain margin for the detection of the touch event.  This value is arbitrary chosen, 10 looks nice in my case.

You can then add the method plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex, which will be called once a point is selected : the index parameter is the index of the point selected.

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    selectedIndex = index;

    // do some other stuff, adding a label for example

    [plot reloadData]; 
}
```

Since the selected point is now located, you can use the function you linked (don't forget to set the datasource of your CPTScatterPlot instance), to redraw the plot. This function is called for each index of your plot, when your CPTScatterPlot instance is reloaded. The trick is, as shown is my code example, to call reloadData when you selected a point.

Comment: Thank you! I am so happy, because it works. :) It didn't work before, because I didn't initialize selectedIndex in plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex. ;)